# Using FromUri as one of multiple Action method parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a hard time binding some data from ajax call to my MVC controller method with the following signature:

```
  public ActionResult AutocompleteHandler([FromUri]Part[] parts, string lastKeyPressed, string term)

public class Part
{
    public string hasType { get; set; }
    public string hasLabel { get; set; }
    public int hasIndex { get; set; }
}
```

The following ajax calls fails to bind the properties (hasLabel, hasType, hasIndex) onto the `Part` object.

```
  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({

            source: function( request, response) {

                $.ajax({ 

                    url: "Controller/AutocompleteHandler", 
                    data: $.param({
                        parts: [{ hasLabel: "label", hasType: "type", hasIndex: 0 }],
                        lastKeyPressed : "S",                     
                        term : "term"                             
                    }),
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            },
```

The number of items in the array binds correctly (so `parts` will correctly have one item in this example)  however all of the properties of that item are at default values despite me passing values.

I feel like I've done this before several times without issue so I'm baffled by this.

EDIT:

The request url is:

```
 `?parts%5B0%5D%5BhasLabel%5D=label&parts%5B0%5D%5BhasType%5D=type&parts%5B0%5D%5BhasIndex%5D=0&lastKeyPressed=S&term=S`
```

Which if I pass to `decodeUri()` is:

```
 `?parts[0][hasLabel]=label&parts[0][hasType]=type&parts[0][hasIndex]=0&lastKeyPressed=S&term=S
```

UPDATE:

Turns out the answer is this only works with an `ApiController` with MVC Web Api not plain MVC.

I will accept answer that shows the equivalent of this in plain MVC because I don't want to send a GET with a body that would be violating HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
$.ajax({ 
         url: "Controller/AutocompleteHandler", 
         data: {
                     parts: [{ hasLabel: "label", hasType: "type"}],
                     lastKeyPressed : "S",                     
                     term : "term"                             
                },
                    dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: Hmm thanks but not working. The request url is:
     `?parts%5B0%5D%5BhasLabel%5D=label&parts%5B0%5D%5BhasType%5D=type&parts%5B0%5D%5BhasIndex%5D=0&lastKeyPressed=S&term=S`  

Which if I pass to `decodeUri()` is:

     `?parts[0][hasLabel]=label&parts[0]`[hasType]=type&parts[0][hasIndex]=0&lastKeyPressed=S&term=S

Comment: The url should be (for this to work) `?parts[0].hasLabel=label&parts[0].hasType=type&parts[0].hasIndex=0&lastKeyP‌​ressed=S&term=S`. That's why I used [FromUri] because it binds correctly in WebApi but not plain MVC. How to make it work in plain MVC is the question. Or an alternative answer could be a model binder for the above url pattern.